# Showing that this is a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:{X}\rightarrow\ [0, {\infty}]$ a function and let $M=\mathcal{P}(X)$ be a $\sigma$-algebra, with $X$ not empty.

Define $$
  l(A)=\begin{cases}
    \sup \left\{ \sum_{x \in F} f(x) \;\middle|\; F \subset A,\: F\text{ finite}  \right\}
    &\text{if $F \neq \emptyset$,}\\
    0 &\text{otherwise.}
  \end{cases}
$$
Show that $l$ is a measure.

I have problems in the part of separating the supremum of a set into a series of numerable supremes.

Another question, the conditions for $l(A)$ be finite are that the direct image of $A$ under $f$ is finite and that the set of $x$ in $A$ such that $f(x)>0$ need to be numerable? I think that the sum of all the values of $f$ in this set needs to be finite too, for the finiteless of $l(A)$.

Comment: Please work on your formatting.

Comment: Sorry, now i´m taking a course on Linux and Latex, i´ll  fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you are correct that for $A$ to have finite measure, i.e. for $l(A) < \infty$ to hold, $f(x) = 0$ must hold for all but countable many $x \in A$. You need a bit of set theory to show this though - the general idea is to show that whenever uncountably many $x$ with $f(x) \neq 0$ exists in $A$, you also find enough "large" ones to constructs finite sets with arbitrarily large sums.

---

The following shows that $l$ is $\sigma$-additive. I assume that you have already shown that $l$ is finitely additive, i.e. that $l(A \cup B) = l(A) + l(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint (this is easy!).

Assume that $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$, and that all the $A_i$ are disjoint. Your goal is to show that $$
  l(A) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty l(A_i).
$$

For and arbitrary *finite* $F \subset A$ $F$, let $F_i := A_i \cap F$. Note that then $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty F_i = F$, and since infinite summations of *non-negative* summans can be reordered freely, it follows that $$
  l(F) = \sum_{x \in F} f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{x \in F_i} f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty l(F_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty l(A_i).
$$
Since this is true for *every* finite $F \subset A$, you get that $$
  l(A) = \sup_{\substack{F \subset A,\\F\text{ finite}}} l(F) \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty l(A_i).
$$

For the converse, pick an $\varepsilon > 0$, and chose *finite* $F_i \subset A_i$ such that $$
  l(A_i) - l(F_i) \leq \varepsilon 2^{-i}
  \quad
  \text{and set}
  \quad
  G_i := \bigcup_{j=1}^i F_j \subset A.
  \quad
  \text{(the $G_i$ are all finite!)}
$$
Then, since $l(A_i)-\varepsilon 2^{-i} \leq l(F_i)$, you get (assuming that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty l(A_i)$ converges - I leave the non-converging case, i.e. the case of $A$ having measure $\infty$ to you)
$$\begin{eqnarray}
  l(A) \geq \lim_{i\to\infty} l(G_i)
  &= \lim_{i\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^i l(F_j)
  \geq \lim_{i\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^i l(A_j) - \underbrace{\varepsilon\sum_{j=1}^i 2^{-j}}_{=\varepsilon(1 - 2^{-i})} \\
  &= \sum_{j=1}^\infty l(A_j) - \lim_{i\to\infty} \left(\sum_{j=i+1}^\infty l(A_j) + \varepsilon(1 - 2^{-i})\right) \\
  &= \sum_{j=1}^\infty l(A_j) - \varepsilon .
\end{eqnarray}$$
Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, that implies that $$
  l(A) \geq \sum_{j=1}^\infty l(A_j) .
$$